# does a large, overcommitted mmap create many page table entries?

Tags: linux, mmap, page-tables

My understanding is that on Linux, if I mmap e.g. 1TiB of memory but don't actually use it, that is "free" because of overcommit, in the sense that it won't actually allocate 1TiB of physical memory, only virtual address space. In particular, all the virtual pages are backed by the shared zero page.

However, 1TiB is > 200 million 4KiB pages, so will this cause 200 million page table entries to be inserted into the page table, so this seems like quite a lot of bookkeeping overhead.

My question is, are all of those page table entries actually created immediately? Or is there also some mechanism for allocating those lazily as well, e.g. with page table entries that have a larger range than just one page.

Comment: You can examine the [pagemap](https://blog.jeffli.me/blog/2014/11/08/pagemap-interface-of-linux-explained/) for that mapping. The CPU's page tables contain the mapping [between virtual and physical](https://docs.kernel.org/mm/page_tables.html) addresses, so only `present` pages have to be mentioned there. The rest will be handled by the kernel's page fault handler on access.

Comment: ^- summary: they are most likely allocated lazily on access, but I haven't checked for myself and I don't see a good source that covers your question exactly

Comment: @teapot418 your linked reference has this quote, which suggests yes but there are no details provided:
"Additionally, on modern CPUs, a higher level page table entry can point directly to a physical memory range, which allows mapping a contiguous range of several megabytes or even gigabytes in a single high-level page table entry, taking shortcuts in mapping virtual memory to physical memory: there is no need to traverse deeper in the hierarchy when you find a large mapped range like this."

Comment: That sounds more like huge pages. Also you would need a continuous piece of physical memory to point towards, so that's after the real allocation/commitment happened.